# How to pass custom attribute from admin category page to List.php

Tags: magento-enterprise, ee-1.12

I'd like to find out how to set up an entry box, so I can pass a string written in it from the "Manage Categories" menu to List.php.

For example, if there's a string "variable_here" for "List Visibility" under "Manage Categories -> Some Category A", you can get this variable via `$layer->getCurrentCategory()->getListVisibility()` in List.php.

Under "Manage Categories" -> "Some Category A"
[image]

How do I add this "List Visibility" box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7984607/387136) as a guide, mind the small bug answered in the comments on that post.
I've also used [this explanation](http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/) myself so that might also be a nice source.

The actual adding of the attribute happens in the installer, it just requires the right resource model.

Both links are on Magento CE but, as far as I know this shouldn't be different in EE.

Comment: Thanks. I was following this: http://www.meteorify.com/2013/03/quick-tip-adding-custom-category-attributes-to-magento/, but your link is better.